# How to solve the tls eof error that occurs when golang https two-way authentication downloads large files

Tags: go, https

I'm running an https service in go and using it to download **large files** from the server, but in some cases, the client **occasionally** has an `server.go:3120: http: TLS handshake error from 1.2.3.4:12345: EOF` error, and sometimes it is *one line and sometimes several lines*.

What is the reason for this error? Is there any good means of locating errors?  Looking forward to your reply.

> go 1.16 and centos 7

> The actual situation is to download large files, which may be **tens of MB or hundreds of MB**

The sample code is as follows

- server code

```
    pool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPath := "root.crt"

    caCrt, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caCertPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ReadFile err:", err)
        return
    }
    pool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCrt)

    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:    ":8080",
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 25,
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            ClientCAs:  pool,
            ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        },
    }

    if err = s.ListenAndServeTLS("server.crt", "server.key"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServeTLS err:", err)
    }
```

- client code

```
    pool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPath := "root.crt"
    
    clientCrtPath := g.Config().CurrentPath + "/cert/client.crt"
    clientKeyPath := g.Config().CurrentPath + "/cert/client.key"

    caCrt, err := ioutil.ReadFile(caCertPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("ReadFile err:", err)
        return
    }
    pool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCrt)
    
    cliCrt, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("client.crt", "client.key")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Loadx509keypair err:", err)
        return
    }
    
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
            RootCAs:      pool,
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cliCrt},
        },
    }
    client = &http.Client{Transport: tr, Timeout: 120 * time.Second}
    resp, err := client.Get("https://localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("client error:", err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    log.Println(string(body))
```

Comment: can you provide a reproduction of the behavior?

Comment: Although I really want to do this, the company project cannot be provided externally, so I use the sample code in the question. What I can tell is that most of the `TLS EOF` problems are cross-country or ocean communication between services.  I'm not sure if this is related to the error, but I'm sure there is no timeout set to disconnect